# Including a shell escape character in a Swift string

Tags: swift, terminal, escaping

The goal is to be able to launch my Command Line Tool and have it automatically resize the terminal window. I found this code to help with that:

```
    @discardableResult
    func shell(_ args: String...) -> Int32 {
        let task = Process()
        task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/env"
        task.arguments = args
        task.launch()
        task.waitUntilExit()
        return task.terminationStatus
    }
```

You can use it like this:

```
shell("ls")
```

Which will make the terminal call the 'ls' command as soon as it runs

Commands like this work great, but the command I need to run is (which will resize the terminal window)

```
printf '\e[8;50;100t'
```

But if I do

```
shell("printf", "'\e[8;50;100t'")
```

I get an error saying 'Invalid escape sequence in literal'. I understand why it is giving this, but I don't know how to work around it. I've tried adding an extra backslash but then it won't actually execute the command, it will just print 'e[8;50;100t' to the terminal.

How can I work around this issue?

Comment: What does this have to do, really, with resizing the terminal window? It's a question about escaping strings, isn't it? What the command itself _does_ is irrelevant.

Comment: I know how to normally get around this issue. But since it is executing the command, it will just execute printf 'e[8:50:100t'  and just print the string instead of actually resizing the window. printf '\e[8:50:100t' will produce the desired results. This specific command that resizes the terminal window is the issue.

Comment: Is `printf '\e[8;50;100t'` able to resize the terminal window?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're not *actually* running a shell, so the escaped form `\e` is not being interpreted as the single character that you want. You need to directly include the correct character in the string. One way to do that is with a [Unicode escape](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-ID286) (see the "Special Characters" heading there): `\u{XX}`, where XX is the hexadecimal for the code point you want.

The `\e` character is originally from ASCII, and its hex value is 1B. Therefore:

```
shell("printf", "'\u{1B}[8;50;100t'")
```

will pass through the string that you need.

Comment: And it should be noted that ASCII character 1B is commonly known as the "escape" character (not to be confused with other uses of term "escape" in this answer).

Comment: I actually deliberately avoided using its name so as not to confuse myself or anyone else, but, yes, it should be noted. :)

Comment: So this is the escape escape? And if you get away from it, it's an escape escape escape???

Comment: There is `@noescape`.